# Laravel Sail Separate Testing Database

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-sail

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash
```

I used above command to install laravel8 and `sail up`

It all works good.

However, I would like to have testing mysql as well.

```
mysql_test:
  image: "mysql:8.0"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
    MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE}"
    MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USERNAME}"
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
  networks:
    - sail
```

I added above to docker-composer.yml and ran `sail up`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql_test
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel8_test
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

`.env.testing`

but when I ran `sail test`, I get an error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'sail'@'%' to database 'laravel8_test' (SQL: select * from `users`)
```

and the test I ran is

```
public function test_example()
    {
        dd(User::all());
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

What else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does not create databases as far as I know. Try to create the database from a database client, like for example dbeaver and than let the migrations run. Hovever it is best practice to use the [memory driver for testing](https://mauricius.dev/sqlite-in-memory-database-for-unit-tests-in-laravel/).